# Real-time updates for new review tasks

Tags: feature-request, review, live-refresh

I would like to see the review page refresh automatically if I have done some reviews and get the message that there are currently no more reviews to perform.

Refreshing the whole page is, in my opinion, a little too much overhead. The review itself seems to work with AJAX. So, a small refresh button to trigger would be nice too, if the real-time updates are too complex.

Comment: Is there any update on this?

Comment: Not as far I know :-(

Comment: I think this is an excellent idea and should be implemented. Now I have to continuously refresh the review page to check for any new review task.

Comment: Is there any news about this post? I think it's a very important feature.

Comment: Not as far I know... You can just upvote it and wait.

Comment: @rekire As the whole SO message system uses push/long-polling to get new message, an additional transfer for the review queues (when you are on that page) should not be a big problem (from technical side).

Comment: It's time for a bounty.

Comment: I would like to note that if this got implemented, it would *only* be the counts on the main review page. It doesn't make sense to live-refresh the error message inside an actual review panel because there's no guarantee you'd actually be paying attention to the page, so if it loads a new review item it could just end up sitting in an inactive tab for who knows how long. That wouldn't be a productive use of resources. A refresh button is your best option for the error page.

Comment: AFIK it is simple to detect if a tab/window has the focus. If not just put the new count in brackets like in the chat, and if the tab gets the focus refresh it then.

Comment: +1 if we can have the total count also auto updated on the tab, like with new questions. [Suggested here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202553/have-total-new-reviews-in-the-browser-tab-like-with-new-questions)

Answer (score 7):

If real-time updates did end up too complex (very likely), I would be in favor of even something as simple as this:

[image]

Where clicking the link would AJAX the necessary parts of the page to check for a new review item.

Comment: Does F5 not count as a check again link?

Comment: Yes, but it would reload the whole page. Ideally, only the necessary parts of the page should be reloaded.

Comment: They already update who did the least review this could been taken as a Ajax reload trigger.

Comment: If this could happen, you could set a timeout to do this, and ta-da! Real-time updates!

Comment: Clicking on the `review` tab (below the `Ask Question` button) refreshes the queue without reloading everything.

Comment: What if push notification to client on new review tasks? We do not need to click anywhere for loading

Answer (score 0):

Most of the review queues are short and the items for review get picked up very quickly. I'm not sure if automatic refresh would do much good as you wouldn't probably sit there and watch the page refresh.You may as well refresh the page or at least a part of it as suggested in the other answer.

For a long queue, on the other hand, any kind of refresh is not really necessary.

It could be different if there was a notification in the toolbar (especially in the new changes that were announced recently). I'm not sure how feasible it would be from the performance point of view as there's a large number of people who would receive those notifications.

Comment: Let's take the example of the late answers queues... If you want to know when it's Ok to review something, you'll have to refresh your page near every 5s... Otherwise your're unlikely to have somehting to review. dyncamic loading would correct this for sure