# /review close votes: Needs moderator flag button

Tags: feature-request, review

While we are reviewing close votes, we currently have the following buttons:

- Close
- Do Not Close
- Edit
- Not Sure

The normal flag hyperlink is not displayed.  There are some review situations where it would be helpful to flag for moderator attention while reviewing.  For instance, these two questions are double-posted:

- [Perl module, inhereting from DBI , "Can't call method 'prepare'" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12656212/perl-module-inhereting-from-dbi-cant-call-method-prepare-error)
- [Perl + POO and Mysql error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12650738/perl-poo-and-cant-call-method-prepare)

I manually clicked to open one in a new tab so I could flag, but it makes sense to me to have a flag button in /review's close vote review menu.  Please consider adding a flag button to the close vote review UI

Comment: May be also interesting: [Real-time updates for new review tasks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148784/171881).

Comment: It would also be convenient for flagging for migrations while reviewing off-topic close votes.

Comment: I must haz flag everything. But, yes.... flagging would be useful for some occasions...