# Why doesn't the review list update automatically?

Tags: feature-request, live-refresh

Referring to the first image below,

What I have seen and found easier to implement is the functionality which updates the **THE YELLOW CIRCLED AREA**, and it could update the **THE RED CIRCLED AREA** in a similar way.

This might not be exact duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148784/real-time-updates-for-new-review-tasks), for which I have [a specific answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148784/real-time-updates-for-new-review-tasks/199143#199143).

In the Review page, the list of the recent reviewers is updated automatically, but the list of questions/answers available for review is not updated. Why?

Don't you think it should be added?

[image]

---

**Note**: I don't want this type of solution:

[image]

---

People who are giving this solution must see this image too:

[image]

---

This already has this type of button, so there isn't any need to use the *Check again* button.

My question is concerned with the other page.

Comment: While the answers to the duplicate are a bit half hearted the question is none the less the same. Note that none of those answers were accepted (or even highly upvoted)

Comment: Its a feature request, if you agree with it upvote it

Comment: You really should attribute that image, you know.

Comment: @Peter nice edit but honestly why bother when this question is closed?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I think an edit doesn't bother whether it is closed or not